# HTTP request builders for GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, http, testing

I’m looking for tools for interactively inspecting HTTP servers by manually constructing requests (and viewing responses), under GNU/Linux. Something that would let me quickly specify standard header fields, make a form request body, etc. (netcat doesn’t really excel at this.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is to make manual HTTP requests to interact with web services for testing / reference purposes, then there is a really nice add-on for Firefox that does just that. It is called [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply cURL is what you need?

Comment: Thanks! Pretty close. Though I was looking for something more visual, of the point-and-click kind, curl would probably do the trick in many cases.

Comment: I think you'll find a GUI for cURL :)

Answer (score 1):

A Python script with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) would seem appropriate. You can manipulate headers at will. Of course you have access to all the request/response fields too. A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml).

Comment: Well, of course I can always do it by myself (I’d probably use httplib though), I was just thinking there might be something ready-made.